# How can I skip previously set waiting times when a key (like Enter) is pressed in C#?

Tags: c#

I'm almost finished with a textadventure. It's a simple console application in C#. For the style I added the feature the program types the single characters and sometimes it's waiting a few seconds until the text continues. If you play the game several times you can find it annoying to read some same parts again and again. So I wanted to add a function that the player can press 'Enter' anytime to skip those times. How can I affort that? To say like "do the waiting stuff until 'Enter' is pressed".
My code for the waiting times rightnow looks like that:

```
public SceneUtility(string text, int speed = 50, int delay = 0, bool input = false)
        {
            outputText = text;
                var t = Task.Run(async delegate
            {
                await Task.Delay(delay);
            });
                t.Wait();
                char[] pieces = text.ToCharArray();
                foreach (char single in pieces)
                {
                    Console.Write(single);
                    Thread.Sleep(speed);
                }
```

I tried putting something above like this:

```
while(!(Console.KeyAvailable && Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.Enter))
{
    //do that waiting stuff above
}
```

I hoped, it would apply the waiting stuff until 'Enter' is pressed but then it didn't show any output at all. Probably it's waiting for any input, now. It's my fault in logic but I don't get the answer, though I'm already searching for hours.

Comment: It would be better if you made an attempt to do this yourself and then post said attempt explaining why it didn't work.

Comment: Basically creating 2 Tasks, 1 sleeping for x seconds and the other one waiting for key input. 1 Task completed terminates the other.

Comment: Ok, I'll edit that.

Comment: Hard to see the hangup or why the Enter key should be special.  Make it KISS with `if (!Console.KeyAvailable) Thread.Sleep(speed);`

Comment: The Enter key was just a thought. Though it just can't be that hard to find the solution. Your solution works perfectly for the Thread.Sleep(speed) part. Thanks for that! But it only works there, not for the delay and not if i put that whole waiting part into that. I'm wondering why?

Answer (score 0):

I like this way:

```
        Console.WriteLine("Press ESC or wait 2 seconds to enter");

        var tHold = Task.Run(() => 
        {
            while (Console.ReadKey(true).Key != ConsoleKey.Escape) { };
            Console.WriteLine("Without wait");
        });
        tHold.Wait(2000);

        Console.WriteLine("You are in!");
```

Comment: I'm not sure if that's quite what I'm looking for. Also it doesn't work on my code.